# How can I loot or pickup the Excalibastard?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

There is a legendary item called the Excalibastard located at the very top of the map Stanton's Liver.   How can I pick this item up?   Pressing E currently does nothing...

Do I have to be at a certain `badass rank`?

[image]

[I have found this site that speculates (also where the picture is from), but no answers yet.](http://kotaku.com/the-borderlands-gun-no-one-can-figure-out-how-to-use-1646384407?utm_campaign=Socialflow_Kotaku_Facebook&utm_source=Kotaku_Facebook&utm_medium=Socialflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the internet,](http://kotaku.com/people-already-figured-out-how-to-use-borderlands-unusa-1646810542) a Badass rank of 2,500 is required:

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Excalibastard), you need a Badass rank of 2,500.

Basically, someone hacked their saved game and kept trying to pick it up over and over until he determined that the Badass rank needed is 2,500.